# Difference between docker run --user and --group-add parameters

Tags: docker

What is the difference between `docker run` parameters:

```
   -u, --user=""
      Sets the username or UID used and optionally the groupname or GID for the specified command.

   The followings examples are all valid:
      --user [user | user:group | uid | uid:gid | user:gid | uid:group ]

   Without this argument the command will be run as root in the container.
```

and

```
   --group-add=[]
      Add additional groups to run as
```

?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`docker run --user=demo_user  <image_name> <command>` runs a container with the given command as **demo_user**
[image]

`docker run --user=demo_user:group1 <image_name> <command>` runs a container with the given command as **demo_user** whose primary group is set to **group1**
[image]

`docker run --user=demo_user:group1 --group-add group2 <image_name> <command>` runs a container with the given command as **demo_user** whose primary group is set to **group1** and **group2** as secondary group of the user
[image]

NOTE: users and groups used for these options MUST have been created in the image of which we are creating a container.
If `--group-add` option alone is specified without `--user` and the image does NOT have any user declared(user should have been created but not declared via USER instruction in Dockerfile from which the image got created), group modifications happen to the `root` user in the container.

If `--group-add` option alone is specified without `--user` and the image does have the user declared( via USER instruction in Dockerfile from which the image got created), group modifications happen to the declared user in the container.

Comment: About your note, are you sure that modifications will by applied to the `root` user. Shouldn't they be applied to the image's declared user instead (i.e. the user you're connected with if you don't provide the `-u` flag) ?

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE. Yes, group is added as secondary group to the `root` user if `--user` is NOT provided AND the image does not have any user declared(user should have been created but not declared via USER instruction in Dockerfile). I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

When you create a Docker image, you can also create users and groups inside it. Those options allow you to connect as a specific user (`-u`) and with additional groups (`--group-add`).

In other words, when you execute a process in a Docker container, you do so as the provided user, and its groups (defined in the system). You can tell the system that the current user has addition groups by using the `--group-add` flag, for the process' lifetime.

Check out the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/additional-groups

```
$ docker run --rm --group-add audio --group-add nogroup --group-add 777 busybox id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=10(wheel),29(audio),99(nogroup),777
```