How can I execute a bash command as part of a variable substitution in a Jenkinsfile
I am executing my Jenkins build in a docker agent. I need to provide additional arguments to the docker run command, one of which is --group-add. The agent section of my Jenkinsfile looks like:
agent {
    docker {
        image "maven"
        args "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --group-add 999"
    }
}

The problem is that the group id is hard-coded in the Jenkinsfile and I would much rather this be extracted at runtime. i.e. I would like to do something like this:
agent {
    docker {
        image "maven"
        args "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --group-add $(getent group docker | cut --delimiter ':' --field 3)"
    }
}

But this expansion doesn't work. I don't think setting an environment variable would help because it would occur too late.
Am I stuck with hard coding the group id value?

I've resolved this issue by defining my agent with a dockerfile. This allows for execution-time expansion of variables.

Just FYI, Jenkins automatically passes -u uid:gid to each container run, so the primary group is already set for you.
Then, to set a secondary group, you have to make sure it actually exists within the container. So if you don't want to hardcode its value in your Jenkinsfiles, you have to extract it from the container itself, not from the host - otherwise, even I'd the group is present, the group IDs might not match.
Getting back to the variable substitutions - obviously, they will not work in such a scenario. But you can take advantage of different stages in Jenkinsfile - run the container first time, extract the group id, save to s variable, then run it second time:
def groupId

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'some-label'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Detect the group ID') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image "maven"
          reuseNode true
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          groupId = sh script: 'getent group docker | cut --delimiter ':' --field 3)',
            returnStdout: true,
            label: 'Extract the secondary group'
      }
    }
    stage('Run Maven goals') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image "maven"
          args "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --group-add ${groupId}"
          reuseNode true
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}

Note the use of reuseNode true that allows you to run the stages on the same agent. I also added an explicit label for it because by default Jenkins assumes that any agent is able to run Docker which might not be true.

Thanks for the answer. Although Jenkins runs the process in the container using its own uid:gid it cannot access the Docker socket in the container because in the container that uid is not part of the Docker group, hence the specific need to add the Docker group to the process in the container. Am I limited to having to set a an agent at each stage and if I am to reuse the agent in another stage, how do I specify that same agent in subsequent stages? Ideally I'd like to specify the agent at the top level and only once.

In fact, my example does exactly what you want. You need to distinct specifying the agent itself from specifying the container along with the agent. In my example, the former is done at the top level while the latter is done at the stage level on purpose. The documentation doesn't say anything about this, but if you try to define both at the top level and then do the same at the stage level again, Jenkins will attempt to run that stage container within the top-level one (and, likely, fail, even if the agents happen to be different).

Apologies, I misunderstood your answer. I will try this but I think I will need to separate the bash script into its own step as it must run on the host. Currently I think the bash script would execute within the container ?

Yes. Running it on the host might also work, but it depends on your setup. This answer has more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41101828/16417367

I cannot get your example to work, do you you have a working version of this? For one thing, there must already be an host agent with the label specified at the top level to be available. I'm not sure what undocumented behaviour you mentioned but it probably isn't something I want to rely on.
